# How to draw another layer of hexagon UIBezier Path and animate accordingly

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, caanimation

I'm looking for a way to add another layer of hexagon bezier path like the ones below.

[image]

I have been able to create Hexagon using bezier path and animate accordingly but I am trying to add another grey colour layer of bezier path. I tried adding multiple bezier paths but it doesn't work.

This is the output I achieved.

[image]

Here is my `LoaderView` class

```
class LoaderView: UIView {

private let lineWidth : CGFloat = 5
internal var backgroundMask = CAShapeLayer()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUpLayers()
    createAnimation()
}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    setUpLayers()
    createAnimation()
}

func setUpLayers()
{
    backgroundMask.lineWidth = lineWidth
    backgroundMask.fillColor = nil
    backgroundMask.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    layer.mask = backgroundMask
    layer.addSublayer(backgroundMask)
}

func createAnimation()
{
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity
    backgroundMask.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let sides = 6
    let rect = self.bounds
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    
    let cornerRadius : CGFloat = 10
    let rotationOffset = CGFloat(.pi / 2.0)
    
    let theta: CGFloat = CGFloat(2.0 * .pi) / CGFloat(sides) // How much to turn at every corner
    let width = min(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)        // Width of the square
    
    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + width / 2.0, y: rect.origin.y + width / 2.0)
    
    // Radius of the circle that encircles the polygon
    // Notice that the radius is adjusted for the corners, that way the largest outer
    // dimension of the resulting shape is always exactly the width - linewidth
    let radius = (width - lineWidth + cornerRadius - (cos(theta) * cornerRadius)) / 2.0
    
    
    // Start drawing at a point, which by default is at the right hand edge
    // but can be offset
    var angle = CGFloat(rotationOffset)
    
    let corner = CGPoint(x: center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta)))
    
    for _ in 0..<sides {
        angle += theta
        
        let corner = CGPoint(x: center.x + (radius - cornerRadius) * cos(angle), y: center.y + (radius - cornerRadius) * sin(angle))
        let tip = CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(angle), y: center.y + radius * sin(angle))
        let start = CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle - theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle - theta))
        let end = CGPoint(x: corner.x + cornerRadius * cos(angle + theta), y: corner.y + cornerRadius * sin(angle + theta))
        
        path.addLine(to: start)
        path.addQuadCurve(to: end, controlPoint: tip)
        
    }
    path.close()
    backgroundMask.path = path.cgPath
}}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't look like a progress indicator"? What else do you want?

Comment: Ah I see. To do that, rather than adding another bezier path, you should add another `CAShapeLayer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the gray hexagon under the blue animating path, you can add another `CAShapeLayer`:

```
var grayLayer = CAShapeLayer()
```

Set it up in a similar way to `backgroundMask`:

```
grayLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
grayLayer.fillColor = nil
grayLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
```

Set its path to be the same path as `backgroundMask`:

```
backgroundMask.path = path.cgPath
grayLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

Finally, add the gray layer *before* you add `backgroundMask`. This makes it go at the bottom:

```
layer.addSublayer(grayLayer)
layer.addSublayer(backgroundMask)
```

Also note that your path drawing code doesn't need to go in `draw`. It could just go in `init`.

Here's what one frame of the animation looks like:

[image]

Comment: I tried adding a CAGradientLayer to replace the blue backgroundMask it didn't work here is the sample code.                                                                           

  gradientLayer.mask = backgroundMask
  gradientLayer.locations = [0.35, 0.5, 0.65]

 gradientLayer.frame = rect
 gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]

Comment: @govindkumar It should work if you don't add `backgroundMask` from the view's `layer`. If it's still not working, consider asking a new question, and provide a [mcve].